# MsgPack could not messagepack NSData object

Tags: objective-c, ios, messagepack

Trying to set an image data

```
NSData *thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(place.thumbnail, 0.8);
            [placeDict setObject:thumbnailData forKey:thumbnail];
```

And getting error:

```
Could not messagepack object: External Data Reference: <self = 0xbba24f0 ; path = nil ; length = 557>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you recive this error after this lines of code?
Use this code to be quite sure that your program have/not have errors in this part of code:

```
NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
NSData *thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(place.thumbnail, 0.8);
NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
placeDict setObject:thumbnailData forKey:thumbnail];
NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I commented this line and it was OK without it. 
But error occurs when I'm running [placesToPack messagePack].

Comment: And what is placesToPack? In your code there is only placeDict.

Comment: array, containing placeDict.